# Javascript does not change image source on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript. I'm trying to change the image source on page load. I don't know why this doesn't work. Could someone please provide me with some insight on it? Here's my html code:

```html
<html>
  <body onload="changeImage()">
    <ul id="character-list">
      <li id="character1">
        <img src="character1.jpg" width="250px" height="280px" alt="" />        
      </li>
    </ul>
  
  </body>
  
  <script>
    function changeImage(){
      var charDiv = document.getElementById("character1");
      var imgTag = charDiv.getElementsByTagName('img');
      imgTag.src = "character2.jpg";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` will give you an array of `image` tags so `imgTag.src` is not going to work in this case.

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: But, the charDiv.getElementsByTagName("img") only returns an array of images inside the element with id="character1".

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName("img")` will give you an array of `<img>` elements. In this case you need to simply access the only image element in that array `charDiv.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]`:

```html
<html>
  <body onload="changeImage()">
    <ul id="character-list">
      <li id="character1">
        <img src="character1.jpg" width="250px" height="280px" alt="" />        
      </li>
    </ul>
  
  </body>
  
  <script>
    function changeImage(){
      var charDiv = document.getElementById("character1");
      var imgTag = charDiv.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
      imgTag.src = "character2.jpg";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot :). So, the charDiv.getElementsByTagName('img') will return an array of image elements inside the element with id "character1", right? And since there is only one image, the 0 index one gives the concerned image tag. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
 function changeImage(){
      var imgTag = document.querySelector("#character1 img");

      imgTag.src = "new desired image path";
    }

changeImage();
```

Seems like simplest way, **if you can't, for some reason, give an id to image**.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ugw4q974/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the same method to get the img as you do for the `charDiv`?
Just give your `img` an ID, and then simply access it by the ID. Otherwise you will get back an array of all `img`-elements.

Comment: Well, the thing is, there elements more than just the image tag under the li tag that have to be changed dynamically. All the elements have to be changed for a specific character. So, I did not want to add a specific id to the image tag.